# Observing @Output Event Emitters in Child Components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

How should be go about using / observing parent `@Output()` event emitters in child components?

[For example in this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-j63hfw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter) the child component uses the `@Output onGreetingChange` like this:

```
<app-greeting [greeting]="onGreetingChange | async"></app-greeting>
```

And this will work if `onGreetingChange` emits in the `AfterViewInit` life cycle hook.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.onGreetingChange.emit('Hola');
  }
```

However that produces the an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

Is there a way to get to this to work without producing the error?

I tried emitting in both the `constructor` and `OnInit`.  Thoughts?

Comment: I created an issue with Angular because ideally Angular would pickup on the state change automatically without the need for another change detection cycle since the state is "Observable".  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the `change detection` manually, using `detectChanges()`

> My guess is that since its a non conventional way of changing an `@Input` change detection is missing the changes, so we need to run it manually!

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.onGreetingChange.emit('Hola');
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pvgqtz?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: @Nuran you rock!!

Comment: In general ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook is not the best place to initiate the value. You should use ngDoInit - right now it is still anti-pattern.

Comment: @NgDaddy When it has to do with the view and eliminating the value change error OP has mentioned, then `ngAfterViewInit` is the solution to go for first!

Comment: @NarenMurali But I cannot see it has anything to do with the view. It is still anti-pattern IMHO.

Comment: @NgDaddy `@Input` property is on the view the property is binded to the view!

Comment: Ok, I've checked and @NarenMurali you are right :)

Comment: But I still prefer `BehaviorSubject` as an `Output` cause it has initial value

Comment: Sure thing @NarenMurali :) Sorry, for asking, but what OP means here?

Comment: I created an issue with Angular because ideally Angular would pickup on the state change automatically without the need for another change detection cycle since the state is "Observable".  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53849

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `EventEmitter`. The advantage lies in the initial value. See this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bncmrb?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Main App

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [AppChild, AppChildTwo, AsyncPipe],
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class App implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Output()
  // onGreetingChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
  onGreetingChange = new BehaviorSubject('Hola!!');

  greetingTwo!: string;

  constructor() {
    //    this.onGreetingChange.emit('Hola!!');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.onGreetingChange.emit('Hola!!');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.onGreetingChange.emit('Hola');
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div><app-greeting [greeting]="onGreetingChange | async"></app-greeting></div>
<div>
  <app-greeting-two (greetingTwo)="greetingTwo = $event"></app-greeting-two>
</div>
<h2>{{ greetingTwo }}</h2>
```

Child one

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-greeting',
  standalone: true,
  template: '<h1>{{ greeting }} Everyone!</h1>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppChild {
  @Input()
  greeting!: string | null;
}
```

Child two

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-greeting-two',
  standalone: true,
  template: '<h1>AppChildTwo: {{ greetingTwo | async }} Everyone!</h1>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  imports: [AsyncPipe],
})
export class AppChildTwo {
  @Output()
  greetingTwo = new BehaviorSubject('Initial greeting TWO');
}
```

Comment: good point.  I built a light weight state service for this type of thing.  You might like it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice

Answer (score 0):

[Per the Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/53849), signals also work in this case.

```
onGreetingChangeSignal = toSignal(this.onGreetingChange, {
  initialValue: null,
});
```

And the template:

```
    <app-greeting [greeting]="onGreetingChangeSignal()"></app-greeting>
```

[Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eqkg5m?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to avoid `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` and it's better for performance

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [AppChild, AsyncPipe],
  standalone: true,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <app-greeting [greeting]="onGreetingChange | async"></app-greeting>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit, AfterViewInit { 
  @Output()
  onGreetingChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.onGreetingChange.emit('Hola');
  }}
```

Code Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-grepmj?file=src%2Fmain.ts